# (MS Access) How to return a field of a different record in a query?

Tags: ms-access

Let's say I have a table with 10 records labeled 1 through 10, and each record contains two fields. I want to create a query that shows me Field 1 of record N with Field 2 of record N+1. For example, the query would show Field 1 of record 3 with Field 2 of record 4. Is this possible?

Comment: You can do this using `UNION` however this seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Brad is right. Can you give a little more context around your question? What is the problem you want to solve? That will help people to give you a [great answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280438/what-makes-a-spectacular-answer), which helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible not particularily complex.
Given a table tblFoo with FooId as Primary Key and the two additional fields FooText and BarText, the SQL to get the desired results would look like this:

```
SELECT f1.FooText, f2.BarText
FROM tblFoo AS f1 
LEFT JOIN tblFoo AS f2
  ON f1.FooID +1 = f2.FooID
```

While it is simple to implement, performance will no be ideal for large tables because the expression FooId+1 prevents the query engine to use the primary key as index while retrieving the results.